# Merging strings in rows of a column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was tryinng to merge strings in a dataframe called df. It is as follows:

```
s=['vic','tory','ban','ana']
df=pd.DataFrame(s,columns=['Tokens'])
```

Please note I am going to use it only for another language, not english.

What I would like to do is to  merge rows in a df column and check the combined words in dictionary and if the word exists, then it will be saved to another dataset and parts of words in df will be deleted as well. For example, I will combine df[0] and df[1] and it becomes 'victory'and then it will be looked for in a dictionary and it is found. Then  'vic'and 'tory' will be deleted from df. How should I do it to work this out? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear. Basically your DF is not a data frame, it's a list. Please edit your question properly.

Comment: How do you know to combine `df[0]` and `df[1]` and not `df[0]` and `df[2]`?

Comment: How many parts are expected to be in a word? Is there an upper limit?

Comment: I would like to combine 2 rows or 3 rows. For example, df[0]+df[1], df[2]+df[3] or df[0]+df[1]+df[3], df[4]+df[5]+df[6]

Comment: I don't think pandas DataFrame is a good datastructure for this problem!

Comment: If pandas is not a good idea, should I use Trie? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of strings and want to check if combinations of successive strings form a word then you can iterate over strings and check possible combinations. To do so you may use just built-in python means:

```
LIMIT = 3  # max amount of strings to combine


def process_strings(strings, words):

    ans = list()

    stop = len(strings)
    current = 0
    # iterate over strings
    while current < stop:
        word = ''
        counter = 0
        # iterate over LIMIT strings starting from current string
        while True:
            # check boundary conditions
            if counter >= LIMIT or current + counter >= stop:
                current += 1
                break
            word += strings[current + counter]
            # word found among words
            if word in words:
                current += 1 + counter
                ans.append(word)
                # print('found word: {}'.format(word))
                break
            # word not found
            else:
                counter += 1

    return ans


words = {'victory', 'banana', 'python'}
strings = [
    'vic', 'tory',
    'mo', 'th', 'er',
    'ban', 'ana',
    'pyt', 'on',
    'vict', 'ory',
    'pyt', 'hon',
    'vi', 'ct', 'or', 'y',
    'ba', 'na', 'na']

words_found = process_strings(strings, words)
print('found words:\n{}'.format(words_found))
```

Output:

```
found words:
['victory', 'banana', 'victory', 'python', 'banana']
```

**EDIT**

Modified version for 1) any amount of strings to combine, 2) cases like `words = {'victory', 'victor'}`, `strings = ['vi', 'ct', 'or', 'y']` - both words will be found:

```
def process_strings(strings, words):

    MAXLEN = max(map(len, words))

    ans = list()

    stop = len(strings)
    current = 0
    # iterate over strings
    while current < stop:
        word = ''
        counter = 0
        # iterate over some amount of strings starting from current string
        while True:
            # check boundary conditions
            if len(word) > MAXLEN or current + counter >= stop:
                current += 1
                break
            word += strings[current + counter]
            # word found among words
            if word in words:
                ans.append(word)
            # there is no case `word not found`, exit only by boundary condition (length of the combined substrings)
            counter += 1

    return ans
```

Comment: That was really helpful. I will test it.

Comment: how should I do it if I want to check strings firstly with the longest length of words in the words list?

Comment: @Kyaw It is unclear what you want to do. Do you want not to use `LIMIT` but to combine as many strings as possible with the total length less or equal to the length of the longest word? If so then you should modify boundary conditions check that is replace `counter >= LIMIT` with `len(word) > MAXLEN` where `MAXLEN` is the length of the longest word - `MAXLEN = max(map(len, words))`.

Comment: Dear Poolka, what I want is when I used the codes, I want them to find the longest word from the word list. For example, if you have words like ‘victor’ and ‘victory’ in the word list, the first search of the combination of the strings will extract ‘victor’ not ‘victory’ but I want ‘victory’ to be extracted from the list. Unless there is no ‘victory’ in the list, the combination will get ‘victor’. I will check what you have proposed here and will let you know if it works.